# How to obtain a list of target filenames given a list of target names?

Tags: c++, cmake

In `cmake` it is possible to get the path to an executable using a generator expression. For instance, if `target_x` was the name of a target, you could do:

```
$<TARGET_FILE:target_x>
```

However, I have a long list of executables

```
    set(EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES_TARGETS
            "target_a"
            "target_b"
            "target_c"
            "target_d"
            "target_e"
     )
```

How would I do the same thing for this list? My current strategy is to iterate over the list and to try and find the property containing the binary filename:

```
    set(EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES)
    foreach (target ${EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES_TARGETS})
        get_target_property(target_file ${target} RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME)
        message(STATUS "target ${target} value ${target_file}")
    endforeach ()
```

But `cmake` outputs the following to console with this:

```
-- target FromFileC value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target FromFileCpp value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromStringC value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromStringCpp value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromFileC value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromFileCpp value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromUriC value target_file-NOTFOUND
-- target AddFromUriCpp value target_file-NOTFOUND
```

Comment: Do you need the properties at configure time or generation time? If the latter, the most reliable way would be to wrap each target in `$<TARGET_FILE:${target}>`. If the former, then the only way I know of is to poll attributes like you are doing -- but there are a lot that adjust output location, and it's not easy to get right in a cross-platform way AFAIK

Comment: Generation time... I tried that actually, I might have got it wrong but I got the same NOTFOUND message.

Comment: "My current strategy is to iterate over the list and to try and find the property containing the binary filename" - Well, it seems you pick up **wrong property** `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME`, which isn't set for the targets. Note, that there are **several properties** which may affect on the name of the output file. But there is no single property which contains the resulted name. Generator expressions (like `$<TARGET_FILE>`) **determine** actual name basing on several properties. If you need that name without using generator expression,  you need to test these properties too.

Comment: Got it, a `foreach` with generator expression worked. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow advice in the comments:

```
    set(EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES_TARGETS
            "target_a"
            "target_b"
            "target_c"
            "target_d"
            "target_e"
     )

    foreach (target ${EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES_TARGETS})
        message(STATUS "$<TARGET_FILE:${target}")
    endforeach ()
```